# nested ajax parent completed before child had finished

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, nested

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("EkranListeleSektor")',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false, //added async later, no changes
            data: { sektorID: $("#ekranSektorID").val() },

            success: function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (i, ekranlar) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("IlAdGetir")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { id: ekranlar.il },
                        success: function (ilAd) {
                            strIlAd = ilAd;
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                            alert('İl isim çekilemedi.' + ex);
                        }
                    });


                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("IlceAdGetir")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { id: ekranlar.ilce },

                            success: function (ilceAd) {
                                alert(ilceAd);
                            strIlceAd = ilceAd;
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                            alert('İlce isim çekilemedi.' + ex);
                        }
                    });

                    divContent += '<label class="styledLabel">' +
                        ' <img src=' + (ekranlar.resimURL).replace('~', '') + ' style="height:150px;width:150px;"/>' +
                        '<input type="checkbox" id="' + ekranlar.ekranID + '" name="' + ekranlar.ekranAd + '" value="' + fiyat +
                                    '" class="styledCheck">' + '<br /><span>Ekran İsim: </span><span class="spanEkranAd">' + ekranlar.ekranAd +
                                    '</span><br /><span>' + 'Günlük Fiyat' + ': </span>' + fiyat + '<br /><span>Ekran Boyutu: </span><span class="spanEkranBoyut">'
                                    + ekranlar.ekranBoyutID + '"</span> <br/>' +
                                    '<span class="spanIl">' + strIlAd + '</span><br/> <span class="spanIlce">' + strIlAd + '</span> </label>';

                    $("#imgDiv").append(divContent);
                });
            }, error: function (ex) {
                alert('Ekranlar Çekilemedi.' + ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

my action part worked correctly i can see coming data with alert and debugger but "EkranListeleSektor" completed before nested "IlAdGetir" or "IlceAdGetir" starting so when i trying to print output to div, strIlAd and strIlceAd print undefined.

Comment: did you see you nested calls being executed (debug tools network) ?

The behavior you got I think is expected. Try moving your div print out to the last nested "success" call

Comment: Also trying by adding `async: false,` to your nested calls

Comment: Do not add `async: false` unless you really know what you are doing.  You are much better off learning how to properly use deferred objects.  Making your calls synchronous is almost always a bad idea and poror user experience.

Comment: I have added answer showing use of deferred via jQuery's `$,when()` method.  You will likely find this a much better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already post my answer in comments anyway I can think in 2 ways to try solving your issue:

1. Add `async: false, to your nested calls`
2. Try moving your div print out to the last (the second one) nested "success" call, but first verify all the calls are being executed using debug tools (debug tools -> network).

Comment: thanks first one worked for me, all ajax calls already worked before, only added async: false part and done

Comment: Setting `async: false` is a hack for actually figuring out how to do this properly which would be to use to use deferred objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should STRONGLY consider using deferred objects here to solve your problem.  Let me give you an example for how you should work this based on jQuery's convenient `when()` method:

```
// This would be code in success handler for your outermost $.ajax() call.
// start "nested" ajax calls wrapped in when()
$.when(
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("IlAdGetir")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: ekranlar.il }
    }),
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("IlceAdGetir")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: ekranlar.ilce },
    })
).done(function(firstCall, secondCall) {
    // This is triggered when both calls are successful
    // set variables
    strIlAd = firstCall[0];
    strIlceAd = secondCall[0];
    divContent += '<label class="styledLabel">' +
    ' <img src=' + (ekranlar.resimURL).replace('~', '') +
    ' style="height:150px;width:150px;"/>' +
    '<input type="checkbox" id="' + ekranlar.ekranID + '" name="' + ekranlar.ekranAd + '" value="' + fiyat +
    '" class="styledCheck">' + '<br /><span>Ekran İsim: </span><span class="spanEkranAd">' + ekranlar.ekranAd +
    '</span><br /><span>' + 'Günlük Fiyat' + ': </span>' + fiyat + '<br /><span>Ekran Boyutu: </span><span class="spanEkranBoyut">'
    + ekranlar.ekranBoyutID + '"</span> <br/>' +
    '<span class="spanIl">' + strIlAd + '</span><br/> <span class="spanIlce">' + strIlAd + '</span> </label>';
    $("#imgDiv").append(divContent);
}).fail(function(){
    // your failure handler, triggered when either ajax call fails
});
```

You can see that this really consolidates your code, getting all success handling and failure handling for both ajax request in a single place.

Performance-wise and user-experience-wise, you will likely find this preferable to using synchronous ajax calls which will block the user's browser from doing anything else while you iterate through each record from outer ajax call and make two nested calls for each.